# Ember-data 1.0 beta 3 model.rollback() does not rolling back children_ids

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the new Ember-data 1.0.0 beta3 and have this issue (which I did not have with 13 revision!)

Giving two models with hasMany relationship

```
App.Post = Ember.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  images: DS.hasMany('image', async:true)

App.Image = Ember.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

I have a lot of images in the application and not necessary that one belongs to post.
Then, I'm trying to push some images to Post from the controller (does not matter from where is this context)

```
assignImage: (image_id) ->
  post = @get('controllers.post.content')
  @store.find('image', image_id).then (image) =>
    topic.get('images').addObject(image)
    post.transitionTo('updated.uncommitted');
```

So far so good, I got a "Cancel" button active because, I have manually sent a Post to "isDirty" state, but the issue is, when I'm doing rollback()

```
discardChanges: (post) ->
  if(post.get('isDirty'))
    post.rollback()
```

I'm not getting the state before I have added the image, I'm mean: it is working for "title" but not for image_ids

Does any one know if it's expecting behaviour or/and how to fix it? 
Again: with rev13 was everything fine :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the good guy mentioned here, and after checking the source
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-1-0-beta-3-parentmodel-rollback-does-not-rolling-back-children-state/3351/3

It' s a current Ember-data behaviour now, I fixed it for now in old-fashioned way

1. Save a separate instance of the children, initChildren
2. Revert to it when hitting 'Discard changes'

Comment: I have the same problem with rolling back children attriutes for a model. But when I try to set the array of my model to the original instance of children, it throw up an error: 'can't set read-only property...